# Only RSA, generated on Android is working properly under Android (5.0+ devices)

Tags: java, android, rsa, android-5.0-lollipop, private-key

I've tried to use RSA. I wanted to check, if all is correct, so I used encryption and decryption (only for testing).

It seems, that only the private key, that was generated under android is working properly.

I'm getting the following error for RSA keys, that were generated via openssl:

```
 java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

For public keys all is working for androidgenerated and opensslgenerated keys.

```
final String RSA_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_ANDROID_GENERATED = "" +
"MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQD8z7AfzAPlOrKUEOH0fewwLHUq" +
"F+kEhETFTYr+5p0IanXKBZPI+hbvk5zKaZkX6FhyiIdwCmyELsQk2L43xkW6YXzg9bL4xSx06VcA" +
"iWDk4onU3K9pVC51Tq1Z+ygg3zvSSoRaUxW3aNHDygx8oIIJpuOQ7x+2TF8sFq1GIy2YdH/Eih02" +
"s2/w3ExykxBn+5rWgj0ZpoWO34umRfQooYeThbJx94v2ap7lOOPPZFiKvH7mUDbOJfb3xcGPynJE" +
"45oDNaew/yOeAjCS/ISHJcZjF8ip7/YKsMRQXCQxzCyUSSEH9ifj90K46H2vx46E7JHBMQk0IuyL" +
"jqL8V3dYhmibAgMBAAECggEAJ9wjG9BR6OmJUHkc9yyHecz4qCte7Pxhz237dVcs+S+35KNeerib" +
"tyhh9zQRFEjo8R3/pLWwCGNLP7gAvdCAG/PU+a8jib+k08YalpYSdeQV8T7eVVAVhx9hi6di21P3" +
"HZ/sIEWrTeCz+he4QkoYVqc+iBJ7wIVoGA53QXC4dqnPZmPcQgaNOAgfz+FTB6ybPduZhL21Qgtq" +
"1IlJ+N5j8mykILj5J1FqCDq5PJA4BwL7f/QK7xRZ8BJGE/6LCmNjXym6C/Dc+uTpIkFiDE2LfgDG" +
"EWVoSnr5kRdt0ucCGPLyCjQ+SrAFtypE6MzL2rC4kfBR1KdXuZB37P+Mlabr0QKBgQD+3yn+Nx4Q" +
"Op8VafH1ntL0vWrQhHoXicisJdWL3dbXELRmEPzOrrlsfhzU5SVLlXBD/eW+aOM745vbQZ9eeBhE" +
"us/QE0ofHPaqy68YFI8IgXSWPGWWimWwNVxZnllAV/8KMU4wRWpcxs7TIbKpRL4EMBk6L610Zq83" +
"1XxqOzqJCQKBgQD97jBdFls+5TQ5u+ws0m8DCtM1kuN+AYFI5UuN6+UBTo1zY/MvolrF5aqTxrUp" +
"xAt6+kPl/0FExIgXJ61kl8o5ZbRGUaZtVUUytDAoJpbYjOzZ7WrRRUwkh5aMmwJraBctR+udkF8N" +
"8+JqiOLbzKRNVWmrw2U7eO3zB/MRi09BgwKBgBpQE9fI/POT+cSOMYq4IPNfct2gL7KqaOtM5KUR" +
"/BIsCVPYQSFdbItE4dkg5x7MiNCcL9HepkcSko6qUbfBElBWMQo8U5SuutCbQrJrvPCV3OF9zsch" +
"9qmgeK5P6Mr5yrzUpkvZfsehRs0JV5aeIDfyd0hIj9HKoCBVjAizoLFxAoGBANLNV+0PUDSIhrCf" +
"J1OWZn46EFjbVmwWx8NCR1TMTlKlaZwvj4Ut3PmIzfDb9y1zCKzQ8mkPXJnAJdJDKBjoQgMgQWZX" +
"Bjihn06Wc5wBXRzs8PuBszmDs9Bnlz2muX187jCzEhC994tXudEDToF2A7gHfjAPiAy1OaSWJt2b" +
"rvINAoGBAP6FnMeqrLEmU14vfPOWBSsPeEPI3kCOUhvMo29SnLx5gdE/gocq5AMEydNt0zIWwLAu" +
"qiO74DIJmK+b10czQg4+sJhk4iQ1cK/k0QQ4wrpu3JDgpgKPFeiyTgPyUHh1O57RCXS2feZAAU2o" +
"napBWm7pfLOyAgoB2Im88GMFTnMY";    

final String RSA_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_OPENSSL_GENERATED = "" +
"MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA+cNkMcWTXY5ZXxwwg0AkrZ5jVyoTTBbYqHWRghrOnpddES48" +
"COot9/oeKElu17Q+AfWTTsWTlR8pQdnVsT1fBQJrZSY/YCsNbKv4BfKnurxOQyck" +
"Tz5ysIitWqJCpiPvRB957jWMIMMPcB/VmI0q6wZ+f7BaTl89QKSR8nWQDgkOdQc7" +
"D/aSUdWckak6ILvZAcjhzR0OL6O6TaeKgHT1g7slexO3haMKbaW8dc1Vgq/D7cAi" +
"EBTGxNQLhEL8LPUnSYeQqzdKqj5xP7AUnT/0EAEX5Oz3zNzZozNDNhcbZXx+xike" +
"s60y+6MPW2ihKBt1G/BwUBj3VpAjdlq1y/2lKQIDAQABAoIBAQDkWGQpMPaLCVLi" +
"JrafuKwP44f1L+2WmiiY02wl4/ZVfhNDWt7eU6OVXKHnuUNSiGJMjkWQNgi4xFWG" +
"8+5v7akKvmyLfI1ikdnjKdJHNdNtYS24LXf/zxsyFLNQ8po2pRHiWVizlVc4uL1L" +
"iH9SynWbjENo4EWf82jfydX5MsxyVrz1qmh5JeQC4VgxFdpz8Q912gfAc+h9QK8e" +
"x6MVP/LoIeDBuQf4+1kmTN3Szyc+y0i1Bfem8NrswlTobBXwV4CcnvX+kArDlOTG" +
"H6+j5murcZe2A/un/mUSC/3hCC84wEkr8uJsZ0JkNRqBga55Rema7AcFIZ04AZvl" +
"gEroQboBAoGBAP6svxtfmBArLNZe+Opm8ena7RG5b9WHFMnrND7in/2GTHQlfteq" +
"csFAKxnuq9BiBlY3Qm65o8etm7GdSRlUwiBy2r8P1RfV6LGRFK/Jzgk9gDh+yJpg" +
"rEEQ6c0n0FJtOloNehP7sYIOSSPqztyFH7QGkTMxqUT+GOfQsal+RnlBAoGBAPsQ" +
"GiinmsSlZ1xaA2knGKIiez7ms1/Dv5BIpjme9JkR7uIg+5WPcFBqufMdQ98OmFlT" +
"u1aPHW3/+eis/R1Y24h30TBH4DvhXz7D+OIUDOTfBEQ83bGSNP4AInhNlCfzDV1Y" +
"SjdMKoGyMxd7tWPxtDkoC3VBbz8dpEMZF3z4FgnpAoGBANC2J6Q6UneluogwqxQG" +
"q+j4FuM4spMusfXMwTNsLKvr/QoOlIYQVR1VBj2pYLtVKlZL0TDHCJcjCv6jpP2S" +
"fclz9xsv0XZIQvwKpwZtf2IJOeSS2rnR0jk8sC8Gmu6CP5j/hHWOBupL5Nr/muoU" +
"W2gBHcvzvgIhr62DVaZPK1hBAoGBAOqsq3by66UCYvIdJXEF3W24Q3GRXXuXUpmA" +
"fvf/T+1AqQVwBRpQoJBaooPQCCAY2Wkt7j/DuKOYkLXf9RyYcWRHcx7pIH14dXoK" +
"3rocOc05dRh/uE4CN0xxPccr5N/OveBR5dV4eYcP1dgOh4frZyXB+6vXxS+++krJ" +
"yn3Cu375AoGASxHCB0gdfYRyWQEl0WoL1eyohdAJf08kVBZtAQ2jLeqY0ZEdUpzG" +
"+99qyw2IysGMwmjCxribLwbUm2cg74lZnX0NQH4HfQ5Pp4c0RUyJARrVzPhyQ1lu" +
"vgPZpCebTX9/118crlHQlTiGD4M258ghR8msm/+p4Efl8NvEcQ35y04=";

byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(RSA_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_ANDROID_GENERATED, Base64.DEFAULT);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);//working    

byte[] keyBytesOpenSSL = Base64.decode(RSA_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_OPENSSL_GENERATED, Base64.DEFAULT);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec specOpenSSL = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytesOpenSSL);
KeyFactory keyFactoryOpenSSL = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey keyOpenSSL = keyFactoryOpenSSL.generatePrivate(specOpenSSLenter code here);//java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
```

Comment: Tested on 5 different 5.0+ devices - not working.

Comment: On one 2.3 device working for both keys.

Comment: Are you sure your key has a correct format?

Comment: RSA not working similar on all platforms? It is only algorithm.
It is strange, that android 2.3 can use all keys, and 5.0+ only some.

Keep in mind, that public keys always work.

Comment: PS: OpenSSH and OpenSSL are quite different projects, although OpenSSH until a few years ago used *part of OpenSSL library* (libcrypto) and *mostly* used OpenSSL privatekey file format (PKCS#1 for RSA). For **public** keys, Java JCE uses the X.509 SPKI structure (only, named `X509EncodedKeySpec`) and OpenSSL does so by default (internally named more simply `PUBKEY`) but OpenSSH uses a very different format. If you want to use one of the Java SSH implementations (which mostly use Java format keys) to communicate with OpenSSH this can be a problem; post a more specific question.

Comment: Sorry for variable names. keyFactoryOpenSSH should be keyFactoryOpenSSL and etc. I renamed all variables in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the OPENSSL version is different from the ANDROID one.

See both data structures in the online ASN.1 decoder:

[RSA_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_ANDROID_GENERATED](https://lapo.it/asn1js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

[RSA_ENCODED_PRIVATE_KEY_OPENSSL_GENERATED](https://lapo.it/asn1js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

Therefore I assume that the OPENSSL version is not a valid [PKCS#8 structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#page-3), only a subset containing the PrivateKey structure.

May be you executed the wrong command using OpenSSL, if I read the documentation correct it creates by default a PKCS#1 structure. If you want a PKCS#8 strcusture you have to convert it later using `openssl pkcs8 ..` command.

Comment: I'd used: openssl genrsa 2048

Comment: @user2247864 In `openssl` comandline `genrsa` does indeed write PKCS#1. `req -newkey` writes PKCS#1 in 0.9.* versions which are no longer supported (but may still exist some places) and PKCS#8 in 1.0.0 and higher. `genpkey -algorithm rsa` which only exists in 1.0.0 and higher writes PKCS#8. As Robert said (almost) **`pkcs8` with `-topk8` option converts** PKCS#1 to PKCS#8. You can more easily see the difference by **looking at the header line** in the PEM file: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` is PKCS#1, `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` (no `RSA`) is PKCS#8.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand.